# Create a copy of a list such that each element of the list is different from the original?

Tags: python

Is it possible to create a copy of a list such that each element of the copt is not related to each element of the original?

e.g

```
t = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

then 
(copy of t)[0] is t[0]
returns False

It seems to return True for all copy functions i tried.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you include the 'copy functions' you tried that didn't give the expected output?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, doesn't copy equal to the original by definition?

Comment: If you think you need two distinct but equal ints, you're probably misunderstanding how assignment works in Python and what you can do with an int. You almost never need distinct but equal ints.

Answer (score 1):

In Python, small integers are cached. So, when you use them, difference integer objects will not be created. The cached objects will be used. That is why you are getting `True` when you compare two small integers with `is` operator.

If you just want to make a copy of a list of numbers, then

```
new_list = old_list[:]
```

should be sufficient.

Also note that, integer objects are immutable in Python. So, you don't have to worry much.

Answer (score 0):

For that you can use `deepcopy` to get a different set of data:

```
from copy import deepcopy    
b = deepcopy(a)
```

Note however, that if your list contains `ints`, then you will always get `True` because the two ints will be the same. Here is what I mean: http://repl.it/R3J/1

However, if you are dealing with something like: `a = [[1], [2], [3], [4], [5]]`, then the method I have stated **does** work: http://repl.it/R3J/2